# How do I efficiently store the 1000 samples generated from one of the 12 sets of parameters in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to solve the simulation problem:
[image]

There should be 12 sets of parameters, and for each set of parameter, I need to generate data and efficiently store them. However, I'm having trouble doing that. Right now I have tried:

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(2000)

n = 500
p = 600
reps = 1000

params <- expand.grid(
  p1 = c(400,550,570),
  c1 = c(0,0.1),
  c2 = c(0.1,0.5)
)

Y<-array(NA,dim=c(n,1,reps))
X<-array(NA,dim=c(n,p,reps))

sims <- function(p1,c1,c2) {
  data <- replicate(reps,(mvrnorm(n, mu = rep(0,p+1),
                                     Sigma = diag(p+1))))
  beta<-matrix(data=c(rep(c1,p1),rep(c2,p-p1)),nrow=p,ncol=1)
  for (i in 1:reps){
    Xi<-data[,1:p,i]
    ei<-data[,p+1,i]
    Yi = Xi %*% beta+ei
    X[,,i]<-Xi
    Y[,,i]<-Yi
  }
  list(Y=Y,X=X)
}

simulations <- vector("list", length = 12)
for(i in 1:12) {
  pars <- params[i, ]
  simulations[[i]] <- sims(pars$p1, pars$c1, pars$c2)
}
```

But this is incredibly slow.

Comment: There are 2 issues, storage: each sim size is about 2.5G and performance: it is slow. With storage, you could save each sim output into a file instead of a list.

Comment: @zx8754 May I ask how I do that? Should I save it as a .csv file to replace `list(Y=Y,X=X)`?

Comment: To keep the object structure, I'd save it as an object, not text file like csv. Replace `simulations[[i]] <- sims(pars$p1, pars$c1, pars$c2)` with `saveRDS(sims(pars$p1, pars$c1, pars$c2), file = paste0("my_sim_", i, ".rds"))`